# Changing subdir multisite install to subdir core directory structure

Tags: multisite, core

Now that WordPress 3.5 is supposed to work with core files in subdirectory, I decided to move my local development setup (subdirectory multisite) to that configuration.

Fast forward and what I have is following:

`wordpress` (3.5 core)

`wp-content` (content dir, configured via `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL`)

`.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) C:\server\www\dev\wordpress/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) C:\server\www\dev\wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ C:\server\www\dev\wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

`wp-config.php` with:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dev.rarst.net');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

`index.php` with:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Status:

- network admin works at `/wordpress/wp-admin/network/` but all links try to point to `/wp-admin/network/` which errors `Forbidden` with `The given path was above the root path: AH00127: Cannot map GET /wp-admin/network/ HTTP/1.1 to file`
- root site works at `dev.rarst.net` with admin at `dev.rarst.net/wordpress/wp-admin`
- other subdir sites (`dev.rarst.net/*`) have broken uploads, and links to admin and stuff, hadn't got to them yet.

The question in a nutshell - **in what direction do I need to move from here to get everything working?**

What admin links are even supposed to be with this setup (since core is in "real" subdir and sites are in "virtual" subdirs)?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/76913/19726

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` lines need to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) /wordpress/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

.htaccess can't access locations outside of the document root, that is why paths like `C:\server\www\dev\` fail. (The code above has been tested on my localhost multisite install).

Because of the `.htaccess` rewrite, you don't need to set `WP_CONFIG_DIR` and `WP_CONFIG_URL` they are calculated by WordPress accordingly. You can access your admin pages at `http://dev.rarst.net/wp-admin` or `http://dev.rarst.net/subsite/wp-admin`

Comment: Yep, removing absolute part of path seems to fix it so it's a problem with network admin spitting out wrong rules. There is open trac ticket [Wrong RewriteRule in a local Multisite installation](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23073) on it.