# Redirecting to page not found mulitiste

Tags: multisite

when you make a new site from the network admin panel, and then go to the site dashboard it comes up with a "page not found" message.

I am working in localhost/mulitsite/

is the redirect url is correct

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpmu/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) C:\xampp\htdocs\wpmu\$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ C:\xampp\htdocs\wpmu\$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite rules should not have absolute paths. This was likely caused by a bug, fixed in WP 3.5.1, see [Changing subdir multisite install to subdir core directory structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78145/changing-subdir-multisite-install-to-subdir-core-directory-structure) question.

Update to 3.5.1 (if you aren't on it already) and regenerate htaccess rules.

Comment: And also I have some files which I directly access from themes folder as site.com/register/ Now on new site it is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
RewriteBase /wpmu/
```

you should have

```
RewriteBase /mulitsite/
```