# Wordpress multisite subdirectory redirect infinite loop issue

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, wp-config

Any time I create a new site on my multisite install, I get an infinite loop redirect when navigating to that site's admin. I'm using the default htaccess supplied by WP for my subdirectory install. Here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) site/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ site/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

FYI - My wp install is within a folder named 'site', and the issue is happening both on my local mamp install and on my hosting server.

Here's the multisite info from my config file:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', APP_URL);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/site/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I've spent the past 2 days googling, but to no avail. Here are a couple of solutions I've tried that didn't help:

- http://tommcfarlin.com/resolving-the-wordpress-multisite-redirect-loop/
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fresh-install-subfolder-multisite-infinite-redirect-loop-sub-blog-login

Any help would be appreciated. I'm starting to get desperate :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar process and so far the redirects work fine for me. Maybe have a look at the following issue [Changing subdir multisite install to subdir core directory structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78145/changing-subdir-multisite-install-to-subdir-core-directory-structure) and see how they resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the [Better HTTP Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-http-redirects/) plugin and enable `wp_debug` in your `wp_config.php` file. This plugin interupts any redirects WordPress performs and gives you a stack trace of the last function called before the redirect so you can trace down what is causing the issue.