# Multisite Subdirectory Site Dashboard redirect loop

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I recently activated multisite and received my code to add to `wp-config.php`.

WordPress wanted to force me to use subdomains.

I wanted to use subdirectories, so I used:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

I then used the .htaccess code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78147/3206):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

However, I still receive a redirect loop when trying to load `www.example.com/au/wp-admin/`:

```
This page isn’t working 
www.example.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I have cleared my cookies and the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

**EDIT**

I created a blank local MU subdirectory site and copied its `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

but the error remains.

Comment: What is the nature of the redirect loop? ie. What is it redirecting to/from/to/...?

Comment: @MrWhite, I am unsure. If I load `/au/wp-admin`/ it redirects to `/au/wp-admin/`.

Comment: "If I load `/au/wp-admin`/ it redirects to" - is that trailing slash part of the request? Check the network traffic in the browser devtools. Knowing what the redirect loop actually consists of is the first step to figuring out what is going on. You should also check the HTTP response headers to determine the status code and what is triggering the redirect(s). The `.htaccess` code you posted should not be triggering a redirect loop. There is only a single redirect to append the trailing slash. ie. `/au/wp-admin` would be redirected to `/au/wp-admin/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to the web host, `WP Engine`, who advised us that an extra license is required to turn a WP site into MU, which we don't currently have.

They confirmed the error was caused by our lack of a MU license.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the feedback. ("WP Engine" doesn't support `.htaccess` either AFAIK - it's simply ignored.)